# Should "duplicate question" close message wording be adjusted when the target question is a repost?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

A user posted the exact same question within 24 hours of each other, changing only the title of the question:

[delegate is nil, can't open my slide out menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524590/delegate-is-nil-cant-open-my-slide-out-menu)

[delegate is nil on view change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541898/delegate-is-nil-on-view-change?noredirect=1)

(both of which seem to be a longer version of [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522450/cant-open-my-slide-out-navigation-panel-on-icon-menu-tap) that s/he also asked.

I Mjölnir'd the dupe but immediately noticed the wording of the close / duplicate message:

[image: Already Has An Answer]

Trouble is, none of these epically long duplicate questions have attracted any answers.

Did I do the wrong thing in closing these duplicate questions, or should I have flagged them for moderator attention?

Or should a different "duplicate" close state / checkbox be made for posters who abuse posting privileges by asking the same question over and over again?

Or should the message be made clearer depending on the state of the question (e.g. "it's been asked before" for no answers, or "it's been asked before and there are answers" for duplicates that do have answers?)

Comment: Normally the message is correct.  This is more of an exception to the duplicate rules.  Normally you can't close a question as a duplicate unless the target question has an answer.  Since it is the same question with the same author though you are allowed.

Comment: I think a different message should be posted for exact duplicates from a user's repost. [I did the same thing.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309558/the-close-text-for-exact-duplicate-reposts-from-the-same-op-states-the-question)

Comment: Or better yet, just diff both questions, merge and delete one.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I see you marked your earlier question as a dupe of this one (!), and I also see the same "already has an answer" message there, even though both your question and mine don't *currently* have answers.

Comment: For more emphasis!

Comment: @Braiam my understanding of why one question is closed, is to make it harder it will be duplicated again and, instead, one who finds it will be directed to the correct place.

Comment: @psubsee2003 IMO duplicates should be closed even if none have an anwer yet (though the message should change), that way, all discussion will take place, in one place.

Comment: @DaniSpringer that gets invalid if the same OP repost the exact same text, don't you think?

Comment: What's "diff"? What gets invalid? And what's "OP"?

Comment: @DaniSpringer diff (GNU diffutils), the thing that list the differences line by line on text data (and lately binaries too), and OP is original poster.

Comment: At this point. I don't understand what my first comment doesn't include. You maybe mean that if the same person posts twice, one of the questions should be deleted? I feel it's enough to have a proper duplicate message fit for that case (if that's what you meant, my bad!), but it seems unimportant, as per helping users out. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @DaniSpringer very early on, you could close a question as a dup regardless of whether it had answers or not.  But they realized it was a problem.  The entire point of duplicates is directing someone to an existing answer.  What's the point of telling some they asked a duplicate question if the original question doesn't have an answer.  So the rules were changed to the current implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure what change you are referring to, but as far as I know, the message still says "has an answer", even if it doesn't. Are you talking about a different problem?

Comment: @DaniSpringer I never said the current message is or isn't a problem.  I only provided some historical context for you and the original poster of this question.  You said `duplicates should be closed even if none have an anwer yet`, and I explain that it was already was done, but was changed as it was less than ideal.

Comment: How was it changed? They still close duplicates of which no version has an answer. Wait I'm confused.

Comment: @DaniSpringer did you read my original comment.  `Normally you can't close a question as a duplicate unless the target question has an answer. Since it is the same question with the same author though you are allowed.`  You can't close a question as a duplicate if the target question doesn't have an answer.  But there is an exception if both questions are asked by the same person

Comment: That's not the current situation. I see plenty of "closed as duplicates" that have no answer, no where.

Comment: @DaniSpringer that is the current design.  Examples please.... most likely they were closed before the rules changed.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear if it is so now. Any pot where I can see specifications required to close a duplicate now? Like any anwer, voted up, marked as correct.. thanks.

Comment: @DaniSpringer: Meta: No restrictions. Main: Same user or not unanswered (aka upvoted or accepted answer). Though nobody says the target is then frozen, so it can cease being elligible.

Comment: (I think I) got it. Thanks!