# The close text for exact duplicate reposts from the same OP states the question has already been answered when it hasn't necessarily

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

A user posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526787/write-a-bst-to-file-java-writetofileprintwriter-f) question. It was badly received and put on hold without any answers. They then posted the same question again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558208/writetofile-method-write-a-binary-search-tree-to-file-java?noredirect=1) (deleted now), so I voted to close it as a duplicate.

The close text at the top correctly states

> This question is an exact duplicate of:

but the one at the bottom of the question body states

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If
>   those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new
>   question.

In this case, there was no answer. I have no proposal, thus no [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), but shouldn't this text be modified to reflect the context of the close, ie. same user's repost?

Comment: Back from the future 15 hours earlier: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309500/3933332